# Mutt will not let me save an SSL certificate

Tags: imap, ssl, mutt, certificate

I have just set up Mutt to connect to my firm's IMAP and SMTP server.  Everything works; but when I launch mutt, I get a warning about the certificate, and am given the option to:

```
(r)eject, accept (o)nce
```

I ***do not*** get an option to `(a)ccept` it or any other way to save it.  I suspect the server is misconfigured  because Mutt says:

```
WARNING: Server certificate has expired
WARNING: Server hostname does not match certificate
```

However, I would still like to save the certificate.  After all, it is more secure to get the machine to accept a particular, fixed, cert than to get into the habbit of hitting `o` every time I launch mutt.

BTW: something similar seems to happen every time I send the mail too.  The SMTP and IMAP servers are on the same machine.

**[UPDATE: partial solution]**

After a bit of RTFM I found out that you can add

```
set ssl_verify_host = no
set ssl_verify_dates = no
```

to `.muttrc`, to disable the checks.  This makes mutt treat the cert as OK, and lets you save it.  The problem is that even after it is saved, you must keep those to settings.  Worse, they are global settings, so if I ever start using multiple servers, they will all be less secure.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Comment: What is the FDQN shown on the certificate?  Can you connect to the mail server using that address instead of whatever you are using?

Comment: Good!  By using the certificate's own address, I can get it without having to `set ssl_verify_host = no`.  Please turn your comment into an official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Might I humbly suggest you wrote up an answer based on your partial solution and using account-hooks?  I'd up vote it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by creating an empty folder named **.mutt** in my home directory. Mutt was searching for that. Why it doesn't create it by default is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: this solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't have to set `ssl_verify_host` or `ssl_verify_date` globally. You can use an `account-hook` to apply them only to a certain server.

Comment: Welcome to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). Please provide some more information like how to apply the account-hooks. Thank you

Comment: You are right, it is only global because I don't understand account-hooks.  But the real solution to my problem is @paradroid's.  Sadly he hasn't written it up as an answer, so I can't accept it :(

Answer (score 0):

This was probably not your particular problem, but you get the same prompt, with no (a)ccept option, if you don't have the certificate_file variable set.